# What are "parent environment variables" in context of JUNIT run configurations in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea

So if I go to `Run Configurations -> Junit ->select some case` I can set environment variables for that particular run configuration. I have noticed that there is a checkbox `Include parent environment varialbes`in variables dialog. What exactly is the "parent environment" here? Is is OS? Is I "project", or maybe something else?

[image]

At the beginning I was thinking that eg If I have run configuration for `TestSubject#someTestMethod` and configuration to run all tests in `TestSubject` then the parent for `someTestMethod` config will be config of `TestSubject` but that seems to be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

These are OS environment variables. You can check the list of variables by selecting **Show** button:
[image]

Comment: if those are from OS, then how intellij runs isolated process that does have access to what is globally defined as OS env ?

Comment: IDE reads the OS environment variables on startup and keeps this map.

Comment: But my question is, how does it isolate java process from reading that variables? If it can "include" than i would suspect that I can "exclude" them by unticking that. So how does the isolation of test process happening?